# Induced continuity or differentiablity on a line on a square

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, piecewise-continuity

Let $k\in\mathbb N_0$, $A:=(-1,1)$ and $f:A^2 \to \mathbb R$ be a function with the following properties:

1. For every fixed fixed $y \in A$ the function $f(\cdot,y)$ is $C^\infty$.
2. For every fixed fixed $x \in A\setminus\{0\}$ the function $f(x,\cdot)$ is $C^k$.

**Question**: Is $f(0,\cdot)$ as well $C^k$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false when we consider

$$f(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2+4y^2} - \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

and $k = 1$.

This is also false for $k = 0$ when we consider $$g(x,y) := \frac{4y}{\sqrt{x^2+4y^2}}- \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

which is defined so that $g(0,0) = 0$, note that $g(0,y) = \frac{y}{|y|}$ when $y$ is not $0$; thus this function is your counterexample. Thus the above question is false for all $k \geq 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your nice example. This of course answers my question but I have a follow up question. In your example the functions supposed to be $C^k$ are even $C^\infty$. So your example is a counter example to all $k \ge 1$. Now the obvious question remains if my question is true in the case $k=0$. In your example you get $f(0,y)=|y|$ which is continuous.

Comment: I have updated the answer (False for all $k \geq 0$).

Comment: Thanks a lot. You could more compactly write $g(0,y)=\operatorname{sgn}(y)$. By that you would also cover the case $y=0$.